# How to prevent resetting a login password in single user mode or from a recovery partition?

Tags: macos, security

There are a few ways to reset the login password of an OS X user account:

- Starting up in single user mode, running `mount -uw /`, `launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.opendirectoryd.plist`, and `dscl . passwd /Users/username`.
- Starting up in single user mode, removing `/var/db/.AppleSetupDone`, restarting, creating a new admin account, and changing the password of another account from System Preferences.
- Starting up from a recovery partition or installation media, opening Terminal, and running `resetpassword`.

Is there some way to prevent people with physical access to a Mac from using them?

Comment: Don't give other people your mac and let them restart it.

Comment: There are always methods to access your data once you have physical access to computer

Comment: A common saying in IT Security circles is "Physical Access = Complete Access." If one person can get in, so can someone else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can be prevented. Boot up your mac with your Mac OS X install DVD, and after it has loaded, go to utilities and select Firmware Password Utility. Select the checkbox "Require Password to start this computer from another source" and type in a password.

This password will prevent people from:

1. Booting CD/DVDs
2. Booting into Single User Mode
3. Booting into another OS stored on another partition or disk

No. 2 is the one where people type commands in it to reset the setup data in which they can go through the setup procedure and set up a completely new administrator account.

However, the best way is to keep your mac with yourself. Anyone with root/administrator access can bypass this feature, by typing a few commands in the terminal. Keep your password secret and complex.

It is also worth mentioning that the EFI password is easily crackable. Some people had success with resetting the PRAM and gaining access, while others used exploits in the OS X system to gain root access and disabling the password using terminal commands. The way Apple encrypts is also very lax and you should make it very much different from your OS password.

Comment: so there really isnt anyway to lock that as well?

Comment: it is possible to lock securely, as long as your user account password is kept secret and that you never ever let people who you do not trust use your mac without your permission

Comment: but my password doesnt matter because you do obviously dont have to have one for them to restart my computer and type in the commands

Answer (score 1):

If you have 10.7 or later, another option is to enable FileVault 2. It makes starting up in single user mode require entering the password of an account that has been allowed to unlock FileVault, like normally your own user account.

[Starting up from the recovery partition won't require a password](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4811). But the list of volumes in Reset Password.app will be empty:

[image]