# resetting admin pw for imac 2007 A1224 10.4.10 thru single user mode

Tags: macos, administrator

I was gifted a 2007 iMac A1224 OS X 10.4.10 with a forgotten admin pw. Command+r doesn't get to any erase disc/reinstall os. Is there a way to change the admin pw thru the command+s single user mode or factory reset or admin username and password.

[image]

Comment: There was no Recovery partition back then. I found this, but I have no way to test if it might work - https://swissmacuser.ch/howto-reset-mac-osx-tiger-password-for-admin-user/ Also https://superuser.com/questions/359521/resetting-mac-os-x-tiger-administrator-password-without-a-disk

Comment: Do you have the installation DVD that came with the Mac?

Comment: [This question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/13623/how-to-prevent-resetting-a-login-password-in-single-user-mode-or-from-a-recovery) actually explains how to reset the password from single user mode.

Comment: yes that worked i figured it out a couple days ago  the single user mode reset it thinks the computers new again just create new admin account and delete the old one.